# SQL report duplicated rows into count into count

Tags: sql

First of all let me tell you I have no experience in SQL whatsoever, however I changed my positions lately and given the situation it'd be easier for me to run some script then check each record in the application individually. Here's the scenario:

I have two tables: 
**Users** with userID, username, email etc.. and
**Documents** with DocumentID and UserID, document name and again some other columns.

I want to create a report that will help me check if users have documents attached to their profile.

What I am doing now is

```
SELECT UsersTable.UserID, 
DocumentsTable.DocumentID, 
DocumentsTable.UserID
FROM UserTable 
LEFT JOIN DocumentTable ON UserTable.UserID = DocumentTable.UserID
```

The problem I am having is that, some users already have 2 or more documents attached to their profile, this is causing a duplication.
For example, in the report I see such rows

1. User1 DocumentA
2. User2 DocumentA
3. User2 DocumentB
4. User2 DocumentC
5. User3 DocumentA

etc.

Is there a way to somehow convert those document to values count based on the UserID? so instead I'd like to see

1. User1 1
2. User2 3
3. User3 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `GROUP BY`.  I would recommend writing the query as:

```
SELECT ut.UserID, COUNT(dt.UserID)
FROM UserTable ut LEFT JOIN
     DocumentTable dt
     ON ut.UserID = dt.UserID
GROUP BY ut.UserID
ORDER BY ut.UserID;
```

Notes:

- The use of table aliases makes the query easier to write and to read.
- The `ORDER BY` guarantees that the results are ordered by the user id.
- The `COUNT()` is based on the *second* table, because there might not be a match.

Comment: Thank you! the solution worked as expected. I approved your solution